# Maintain variable when dynamic LinkButton is clicked

Tags: asp.net

I stripped down my solution so that I can understand why this is not working. Hopefully, someone can help.

There is only one placeholder control on the aspx page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Placeholder1" runat="server" />
```

On the code behind, I am setting a variable called **test** and on Page_Load, changing the variable to something else.  How come, when I click the dynamically added LinkButton, the **test** variable is not maintaining it's state:

```
    public string test = "Hello";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Write(test + "<br />");  //test = "Hello"
            test = "Hello World!";
            Response.Write(test + "<br />");  //test = "Hello World!"
        }
        Placeholder1.Controls.Clear();
        CreateDynamicControl();
    }

    private void CreateDynamicControl()
    {
        LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
        lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lbl_Click);
        lnk.Text = "TEST LinkButton";
        Placeholder1.Controls.Add(lnk);
    }

    void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
        Response.Write("lbl_Click: " + test + "<br />");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET variables don't maintain their state between postbacks. You can use Session or ViewState to preserve the values you need.

```
ViewState["test"] = "Hello World!";
Response.Write(ViewState["test"]);
```

Comment: Since I dummied down the solution, I actually need to maintain a Collection across the postback.  Should I still use ViewState or even a Session?  Which would be better?

Comment: Really any serializable object can be stored in a ViewState or Session. ViewState is a hidden field on the page - and gets sent back and forth to the client. Session stays on the server but isn't limited to just one page. Any values set will remain for the duration of the session. If it's a big collection or sensitive data, I'd keep it on the server (Session). If it's small and only used on that page, use ViewState.